# How do I fix a Nikon D5000 pop-up flash which won't stay down?

Tags: flash, repair, popup-flash, nikon-d5000

My Nikon D5000 had an accident and the camera flash now doesn't lock properly and instead it keeps popping up. Do you know how to fix this, have any hints on what to look for or if there's any place in the UK that I can trust to fix it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Nikon has a list of authorized [service centres](http://www.europe-nikon.com/en_GB/service_support/Support_Repair_Home.page) in the UK.

I would not pay for repairs if I was charged for it... I would simply stick tape to it to avoid having it pop up. But if you worry about the looks, do contact the service centre as the latch is probably cracked in your camera. I doubtful about it getting fixed as the latch is a part of the camera, though...